# jq: how to filter an array of objects based on values in an inner array?

Tags: arrays, json, select, jq, negation

Given this input:

```
[
  {
    "Id": "cb94e7a42732b598ad18a8f27454a886c1aa8bbba6167646d8f064cd86191e2b",
    "Names": [
      "condescending_jones",
      "loving_hoover"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "186db739b7509eb0114a09e14bcd16bf637019860d23c4fc20e98cbe068b55aa",
    "Names": [
      "foo_data"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "a4b7e6f5752d8dcb906a5901f7ab82e403b9dff4eaaeebea767a04bac4aada19",
    "Names": [
      "jovial_wozniak"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "76b71c496556912012c20dc3cbd37a54a1f05bffad3d5e92466900a003fbb623",
    "Names": [
      "bar_data"
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm trying to construct a filter with [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) that returns all objects with `Id`s that **do not** contain "data" in the inner `Names` array, with the output being newline-separated.  For the above data, the output I'd like is:

```
cb94e7a42732b598ad18a8f27454a886c1aa8bbba6167646d8f064cd86191e2b
a4b7e6f5752d8dcb906a5901f7ab82e403b9dff4eaaeebea767a04bac4aada19
```

I think I'm somewhat close with this:

```
(. - select(.Names[] contains("data"))) | .[] .Id
```

but the `select` filter is not correct and it doesn't compile (get `error: syntax error, unexpected IDENT`).

Answer (score 693, accepted):

Very close! In your `select` expression, you have to use a pipe (`|`) before `contains`.

This filter produces the expected output.

```
. - map(select(.Names[] | contains ("data"))) | .[] .Id
```

The [jq Cookbook](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook#filter-objects-based-on-the-contents-of-a-key) has an example of the syntax.

> ## Filter objects based on the contents of a key
>
> E.g., I only want objects whose genre key contains "house".
>
> ```
> $ json='[{"genre":"deep house"}, {"genre": "progressive house"}, {"genre": "dubstep"}]'
> $ echo "$json" | jq -c '.[] | select(.genre | contains("house"))'
> {"genre":"deep house"}
> {"genre":"progressive house"}
> ```

[Colin D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26701538/how-to-filter-an-array-of-objects-based-on-values-in-an-inner-array-with-jq/26701851?noredirect=1#comment65634694_26701851) asks how to preserve the JSON structure of the array, so that the final output is a single JSON array rather than a stream of JSON objects.

The simplest way is to wrap the whole expression in an array constructor:

```
$ echo "$json" | jq -c '[ .[] | select( .genre | contains("house")) ]'
[{"genre":"deep house"},{"genre":"progressive house"}]
```

You can also use the map function:

```
$ echo "$json" | jq -c 'map(select(.genre | contains("house")))'
[{"genre":"deep house"},{"genre":"progressive house"}]
```

map unpacks the input array, applies the filter to every element, and creates a new array. In other words, `map(f)` is equivalent to `[.[]|f]`.

Comment: Thanks, works great! I did actually see that example, I just failed at adapting it to my scenario :-)

Comment: Is there anyway to "preserve the json structure of the array"? I like the genre example but it outputs two "json lines". I couldn't figure out the map part necessarily

Comment: @ColinD I wasn't really happy with the reduce solution, so I replaced it with an explanation of the map function. Does that help?

Comment: @IainElder - What happens when the part of the search term (in this case house) is a variable? So say using --args term se. So contains("hou$term")

Comment: @Chris The variable `$term` would be treated as a string, so you should use string concatenation: `contains("hou" + $term)`

Comment: @IainElder -  Of course! String concatenation, didn't realise it was supported - thanks.

Comment: what if `contains` is not OK for me because the string I look for is prefix of a string I _do not_ look for?

Comment: short examples: positive filter: keep values from array: `jq -n '[1,2,3] | map(select(. == 1))'` and `jq -n '[1,2,3] | .[] | select(. == 1)'` and `jq -n '[ [1,2,3] | .[] | select(. == 1) ]'` and `jq -n '[{"a":1},{"b":2},{"c":3}] | map(select(.a == 1))'` -- negative filter: remove values from array: `jq -n '[1,2,3] | . - map(select(. == 1))'` -- filter values by a filter list: `jq -n '[1,2,3] | map(select(. as $val | [1,2] | index($val) != null))'`

Comment: And if you need exact match, `.genre == "house"` works a well.

Answer (score 37):

Here is another solution which uses [any/2](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#any,any(condition),any(generator;condition))

```
map(select(any(.Names[]; contains("data"))|not)|.Id)[]
```

with the sample data and the `-r` option it produces:

```
cb94e7a42732b598ad18a8f27454a886c1aa8bbba6167646d8f064cd86191e2b
a4b7e6f5752d8dcb906a5901f7ab82e403b9dff4eaaeebea767a04bac4aada19
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for - why does this work with a semi-colon `.Names[] ; contains()` and not with a pipe `.Names[] | contains()`?

Comment: Ah, it's the `any(generator; condition)` form.  I found that without using `any()` I would end up with duplicates in my results if `select()` matched more than once on the same object.

Answer (score 6):

Filter ([demo](https://jqplay.org/s/yp_Qy0X_5Xe)):

```
.[] | select( [ .Names[] | contains("data") ] | any) | .Id
```

Explanation:

- `.[]` unpacks the array so that we iterate over each element in the array
- `select(<condition>)` keeps only those elements where the condition is satisfied. The condition is that at least one name in the `.Names` array of that element has the word `data` in it.

  - `.Names[] | contains ("data")` unpacks the `.Names` array of each element and checks whether each name contains the text `data`. At this point, we have an array of bools of the same length as a `.Names` array of that element.
  - `[.Names[] | contains ("data") ] | any` takes that array of bools and collapses it into a single boolean because the `any` function checks that at least one element in that array is `true`. The `select` uses this value as the condition effectively.
- `.Id` plucks the `Id` attribute of the elements that came through.

Answer (score 2):

Following jq map select expression produces the intended outcome:

```
aws ecr describe-images \
  --registry-id <aws_account_id> \
  --repository-name <ecr_repository_name> \
  --region <aws_region> \
  --no-cli-pager \
  --filter tagStatus=TAGGED \
| jq '.imageDetails | map(select(.imageTags[] | contains ("version_tag")))'
```

Comment: A bit more detail would be great

Comment: This would produce duplicates if the `version_tag` string appears more than once in the same `imageTags` element. Likely not an issue with the AWS API, but might matter if used as a general solution (https://jqplay.org/s/iMB4Guum9HF).