# Getting a list of keys based on another property in json with jq

Tags: arrays, json, indexof, jq

I'm trying to create a jq filter for JSON, similar to [How to filter an array of objects based on values in an inner array with jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26701538/how-to-filter-an-array-of-objects-based-on-values-in-an-inner-array-with-jq) - but even using that as a basis doesn't seem to be giving me the results I want.

Here's my example json

```
[{"id":"0001","tags":["one","two"]},{"id":"0002", "tags":["two"]}]
```

I want to return a list of IDs where tags contains "one" (not partial string match, full element match).

I have tried some variations, but can't get the filter right.

```
. - map(select(.resources[] | contains("one"))) | .[] .id
```

Returns `"0001","0002"`

Have also tried `... .resources[].one)) | ...` but always get full list when trying to filter by "one" and expecting to only get `0001`

Where am I filtering wrong? (have about 30 minutes experience with jq, so please excuse my ignorance if it's something obvious :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
map(select(.tags | index("one")) | .id)
```

Since your problem description indicates you want to check if the array contains "one", it's simplest to use *index*.

#### UPDATE

On Jan 30, 2017, a builtin named `IN` was added for efficiently testing whether a JSON entity is contained in a stream. It can also be used for efficiently testing membership in an array. In the present case, the relevant usage would be:

```
map(select(.tags as $tags | "one" | IN($tags[])) | .id)
```

If your jq does not have `IN/1`, then so long as your jq has `first/1`, you can use this equivalent definition:

```
def IN(s): . as $in | first(if (s == $in) then true else empty end) // false;
```

(In practice, `index/1` is usually fast enough, but its implementation currently (jq 1.5 and versions through at least July 2017) is suboptimal.)

Comment: I don't see `index` has a predefined function. Looking through the docs, it looks like `in` might be a function that would help.  However, using in gives me errors - `error: in is not defined`. jq --version is 1.3

Comment: Downloaded jq 1.4 and index works.   Turns out that I wasn't expecting my output properly, and `contains` and `index` are giving the same result: the inverse of what I'm expecting. I get a list of ID's that DONT contain the specified tag.

Comment: I had a `-` at the start of my expression. when I dropped it and used your expression as-is, it actually does work @peak. marking answer as correct, thanks for your help.