# how to select a json object where a child value array contains a certain propery

Tags: json, jq

I have an array of objects similar to the following:

```
[
  {
    "id": "one",
    "tags": {
      "my.key": "true"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "two",
  }
]
```

How can I select all "id" values for each object containing a tag where "my.key" is "true"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `select` with `.tags["my.key"] == "true"` and get only the `id` field :

```
jq '.[] | select(.tags["my.key"] == "true") | .id' data.json
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response! I also got an alternative solution based on [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26701851/62667): `map(select(.tags["my.key"] == "true")) | .[] .id`

Comment: which is pretty much the same thing. I had a typo in my "select" syntax which you helped me to find, thanks :)