# How to filter an array of objects based on values of string in an inner array with jq

Tags: json, jq

I have a json file like this:

`[{
    "path": "p1"
    "title": "t1"
    "tags": ["tags1"]
},
{
    "path": "p2"
    "title": "t2"
    "tags": ["tags1", "tag2"]
},
{
    "path": "p3"
    "title": "t3"
    "tags": ["tags2"]
}
]`

and I would like to filter (using `jq`) the value based on tags and get the title as output.

For instance, I would filter all the values that have *tags1*(and the output would be `t1` and `t2`).

How can I do that ?

Thank you for your answers.

P.S. : I found this question : [How to filter an array of objects based on values in an inner array with jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26701538/how-to-filter-an-array-of-objects-based-on-values-in-an-inner-array-with-jq) that almost have the answer but I was not able to adapt it.

Answer (score 1):

After rectifying the JSON input, the following filter produces the output shown below:

```
.[] | select( .tags | index("tags1") ) | .title
```

Output:

```
"t1"
"t2"
```