# jq: how to query for array values that don't contain text "foo"?

Tags: json, jq

I have an aws query where I want to filter all the `imageTags` that **don't** end with *latest*.

I tried this, but it filters things containing *latest*, where I want to filter things **not** containing *latest* (or **not** ending with *latest*):

```
aws ecr describe-images --repository-name <repo> --output json \
  | jq '.[]' \
  | jq '.[]' \
  | jq "select ((.imagePushedAt < 14893094695) and (.imageTags[] | contains(\"latest\")))"
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete verifiable example (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  One reason is that your problem description is unclear as to whether it requires the use of `any` (or equivalent).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter an array of objects based on values in an inner array with jq?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26701538/how-to-filter-an-array-of-objects-based-on-values-in-an-inner-array-with-jq)

Answer (score 129, accepted):

You can use `not` to reverse the logic

```
(.imageTags[] | contains(\"latest\") | not)
```

Also, I'd imagine you can simplify your pipeline into a single `jq` call.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering,
I tried to run it but I get:

aws ecr describe-images --repository-name embed-service --output json | jq '.[]' | jq '.[]' | jq "select (.imageTags[] | contains(\"latest\") | not)"

jq: error: Cannot iterate over null

But I do have imageTags without "latest"

Comment: How strange. Any chance you can give an example of the JSON you're dealing with?

Comment: The mental gap I was missing is that `contains()` is a terminal filter that just returns `true` or `false`.  To invert it just pipe it to `not`!  It's so obvious in hindsight...

Comment: @GavrielFishel:  that message means that some of the images don't have tags.  Try this to fix it   "aws ecr describe-images --repository-name embed-service --output json | jq '.[]?' | jq '.[]?' | jq "select (.imageTags[]? | contains(\"latest\") | not)"

Comment: Just note that if you are doing multiple evaluations this has to come in the same pipeline you're reversing. `.stuff[] | contains("thing") | not`, not `(.stuff[] | contains("thing")) | not`.

Answer (score 8):

## Use `| not`

A useful example, in particular for mac `brew` users:

#### List all bottled formulae

by querying the JSON and parsing the output

```
brew info --json=v1 --installed | jq -r 'map(
    select(.installed[].poured_from_bottle)|.name) | unique | .[]' | tr '\n' ' '
```

#### List all non-bottled formulae

by querying the JSON and parsing the output and using `| not`

```
brew info --json=v1 --installed | jq -r 'map(                                                                                                                          
  select(.installed[].poured_from_bottle | not) | .name) | unique | .[]'
```

Answer (score 5):

In this case `contains()` doesn't work properly, is better use the `not` of `index()` function

```
select(.imageTags | index("latest") | not)
```

Answer (score 5):

This `.[] | .[]` can be shorten to `.[][]` e.g.,

```shell
$ jq --null-input '[[1,2],[3,4]] | .[] | .[]'
1
2
3
4
$ jq --null-input '[[1,2],[3,4]] | .[][]'
1
2
3
4
```

To check whether a string does not contain another string, you can combine `contains` and `not` e.g.,

```shell
$ jq --null-input '"foobar" | contains("foo") | not'
false
$ jq --null-input '"barbaz" | contains("foo") | not'
true
```

You can do something similar with an array of strings with either `any` or `all` e.g.,

```shell
$ jq --null-input '["foobar","barbaz"] | any(.[]; contains("foo"))'
true
$ jq --null-input '["foobar","barbaz"] | any(.[]; contains("qux"))'
false
$ jq --null-input '["foobar","barbaz"] | all(.[]; contains("ba"))'
true
$ jq --null-input '["foobar","barbaz"] | all(.[]; contains("qux"))'
false
```

Say you had file.json:

```json
[ [["foo", "foo"],["foo", "bat"]]
, [["foo", "bar"],["foo", "bat"]]
, [["foo", "baz"],["foo", "bat"]]
]
```

And you only want to keep the nested arrays that don't have any strings with `"ba"`:

```shell
$ jq --compact-output '.[][] | select(all(.[]; contains("bat") | not))' file.json
["foo","foo"]
["foo","bar"]
["foo","baz"]
```

Comment: all() and any() did the trick for me! Thanks!