# how to filter json list with jq containing a number of values

Tags: json, filtering, jq

I am banging my head how to exclude a number of records from a json list with attributes having a number of values.
[jq - How to filter a json that does not contain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42746828/jq-how-to-filter-a-json-that-does-not-contain)
this is example is for one.

This works fine

```
jq -C 'select( .Image | contains("rancher"))'
```

the negation works fine too

```
jq -C 'select( .Image | contains("rancher")|not)'
```

but extending this to exclude more than one value eludes me

```
echo $JSON | jq 'select( .Image | contains("rancher")|not or .Image | contains("jenkins")| not)'
```

give me:
jq: error (at :1): boolean (true) and string ("jenkins") cannot have their containment checked
parse error: Expected value before ',' at line 1, column 147

Comment: "not (A or B)" equals "(not A) and (not B)", and "(not A) or (not B)" equals "not (A and B)". See [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Answer (score 0):

So the negation is the issue. the jq pipe changes from strings to boolean so its important where to write the negation with not.

this is working

```
'select( .Image | contains("rancher") or contains("jenkins") or contains("google") |not)'
```

**However**
this is a much cooler way to do it by removing the entries directly from the list:

```
echo $JSONTABLE|jq -C 'del (.[]|select( .Image | contains("rancher") or contains("jenkins")))' > table.json
```