# How can I catch VpcId if I know a related tag's value ahead?

Tags: json, jq, json-query

I have the following output of `aws ec2 describe-vpcs`:

```
{
    "Vpcs": [
        {
            "VpcId": "vpc-1f0e197d",
            "InstanceTenancy": "default",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Value": "Product-Production",
                    "Key": "Name"
                }
            ],
            "CidrBlockAssociationSet": [
                {
                    "AssociationId": "vpc-cidr-assoc-f3c5509a",
                    "CidrBlock": "172.19.0.0/16",
                    "CidrBlockState": {
                        "State": "associated"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "State": "available",
            "DhcpOptionsId": "dopt-37fd5550",
            "CidrBlock": "172.19.0.0/16",
            "IsDefault": false
        },
        {
         another vpc...
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm using `jq` to catch the "VpcId" if

```
.Tags[].Value==Product-Production
```

but no matter what I try, I can't get the right syntax, how can it be achieved?

Comment: This is so-close to being duplicate of [How to filter an array of objects based on values in an inner array with jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26701538/how-to-filter-an-array-of-objects-based-on-values-in-an-inner-array-with-jq), but need to modify the answer to suit your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are so-close but not quite the right filter. You need to use a `select` expression here to match the object matching your string condition and filter the value out of it.

```
jq '.Vpcs[] | select( .Tags[].Value| contains("Product-Production")) | .VpcId'
```

If you break down the filter,

1. The part `.Vpcs[]` lists all the elements within the array on which we apply the condition.
2. We filter that object whose `.Value` contains the string you need here. So at the end of first pipe-line output you get the actual element from the list of the elements in the array, matching the condition defined.
3. From the object returned, you just print out the `.VpcId` with the last pipeline.

If you haven't used [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/TRWwWJVS5x) before, you should try it and get your filters into action and work it out online.