# Extract k8s events specific column

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm troubleshooting liveness probe failures. I'm able to extract specific entries from k8s event using this approach

```
k get events --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp | grep Liveness
```

I'd like to get only the pod(s) that causing the issue.
I'm considering to pipe a cut, but I'm not sure which delimiter should I use to get the specific column.

Where I can find the delimiter related to that specific k8s resource(Events) used to printout the kubectl output?

Any other suggestion is appreciated

UPDATE
so far these are the best options (w/o using extra tools) satisfying my specific needs:

```
k get events -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.involvedObject.name}/{.involvedObject.namespace}: {.message}{"\n"}{end}' | grep Liveness

k get events -o custom-columns=POD:.involvedObject.name,NS:.involvedObject.namespace,MGG:.message | grep Liveness
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a feature in kubernetes called [jsonpath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/)

validate if your jsonpath is correct with this online tool: https://jsonpath.com/

easily go through json keys with this online tool, so you needn't manually type the key names any more): http://jsonpathfinder.com/

so your command will be:

```
k get events --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp --jsonpath '{ .xxxxxx }'
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks @BMW for suggesting the tool, it sounds very useful, I'll check it out. Yes, I'm aware about jsonpath but can I also use it also for filtering purpose such as I'm doing w/ "grep Liveness"? I understood jsonpath was more for extracting/querying fields while field-selector should be the way to filter data (but it does not apply to any resource field - where can I found the supported fields x each k8s resource?)

Comment: could you provide some sample codes for me to reference? I run the `events` command locally, but didn't see this key `Liveness`. Can't help more.

Comment: you have to create a pod w/ a failing livenessProbe so you'll get the string within the k8s event as describe by @rebello post here above

Answer (score 1):

Jsonpath is a little bit limited to be used with filter and conditions, maybe for your case `jq` will be more suitable.

I did a test using `jq` to filter the Output of my probe:
I've tested using the yaml from this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/)

The message of probe failure from this pod is:

> Liveness probe failed: cat: can't open '/tmp/healthy': No such file or directory

and the path for this message in json is `.items[*].message`

Using `jq` I can filter only `message` that contains "Liveness probe failed": and show the pod name:

```
k get events --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp -o json | jq -c '.items[] | select(.message|test("Liveness probe failed")) | .metadata.name'
```

The output is:

```
"liveness-exec.15e791c17b80a3c1"
```

You can use `jq` to format the message in order to get a more helpful output, with pod details.

Try to look this references links:

[./jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

[filter array based on values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26701538/how-to-filter-an-array-of-objects-based-on-values-in-an-inner-array-with-jq)

I hope it helps!

Comment: That's great but I wonder if it can be accomplished using standard k8s tools and standard linux tool (eg. grep, cut..)