# Filter an array of JSON objects using a regex test condition

Tags: json, regex, select, jq

I often get sent HAR files (which are JSON) sent to me that look like this:

```
{
    "log": {
        "entries" : [
            {
                "request" : {
                    "url" : "test.css"
                }
            },
            {
                "request" : {
                    "url" : "test.ok"
                }
            },
            {
                "request" : {
                    "url" : "test.font"
                }
            },
            {
                "request" : {
                    "url" : "ok"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I don't care about requests that contain URLs for fonts, CSS, or JavaScript. So, I'd like to remove these requests using `jq`. Given the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26701851/150435) from @[iain-samuel-mclean-elder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/111424/iain-samuel-mclean-elder) about filtering and maintaining the JSON structure of the input, I would expect something like this to work:

`jq '[ .[] | select(.log.entries[].request.url | test("\\.(js|css|font)") | not) ]' < MyGoodHarFile.json`

This, however, produces the error:

`jq: error (at <stdin>:25): Cannot iterate over null (null)`

What am I doing wrong? How can I create a valid HAR file excluding requests for these certain matching URLs using `jq`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be really careful where and how `select` statements are used. Avoiding the error of incorrect parent path `.[]` in your original filter

```
[select(.log.entries[].request.url | test("\\.(js|css|font)") | not)]
```

will produce the whole input twice because the filter asserts `true` for two of your objects because `select()` replicates the entire input on `true` condition.

By virtue of doing `.log.entries|=`, your input is now only on the array of objects which when asserted `true` through regex are retained and the others excluded.

```
jq '.log.entries |= ( map ( select ( .request.url | test("\\.(js|css|font)") |not ) ) )'
```

Comment: Very much appreciated, @inian! I removed the extra `(` before map to try to keep it as simple as possible. Works perfectly though. Thanks for the explanation and help.